# jQuery Fancybox 2 Refresh the iFrame OR Page that is it's parent

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

Basically, I love fancyboxes inside of fancyboxes for data entry.  Problem is when I am done, I wish that it would refresh the fancybox that called it!

Take the example below.  I have a report on The Browser Window, Then details on the First Fancy box, then inside and called from it, a fancybox so I can throw a note in....  After I am doing adding the note, and the fancy box is unloaded, I would like to fire a refresh on the parent fancybox, or whatever called it (7 fancyboxes, close #7 and #6 refreshes)

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-PZlJoSXZSj0/UDWnwAkat0I/AAAAAAAAAPE/SyAPgaSTc1Y/s1600/test.jpg

This code I have here always refreshes the window in the above example. I wish I could get it to refresh the fancybox's parent fancybox!

```
    $('.'+sFancy).fancybox({ 
            'href'  : this.href, 
            'width' : '100%', 
            'height' : '100%', 
            'fitToView' : false,
            'autoSize'  :   false,
            'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
            'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
            'speedIn'   :   200, 
            'speedOut'  :   500, 
            'type' : 'iframe',
            'onClosed'      : function(){
            self.parent.location.reload(true);
            }   
    });
```

Comment: This option will refresh the iframes, but when I close the last fancybox / iframe it won't refresh the base browser window.  Is there a way to test and invoke the correct one?



`'onClosed'      :  function(){window.location.reload();}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for my purposes now.

I have added a function dynamically to fancybox for the last one closed being closed to refresh the parent.

This would answer the question I initially asked:

```
function fancyCall()
{
    var sFancy = 'fancybox';

    if(url.search(/CRMPopper/i) != -1)
        sFancy = 'fancyboxpop';

    $('.'+sFancy).fancybox({ 
        'href'          :   this.href, 
        'width'         :   '100%', 
        'height'        :   '100%', 
        'fitToView'     :   false,
        'autoSize'      :   false,
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   100, 
        'speedOut'      :   300, 
        'type'          :   'iframe',
        'onClosed'      :   function(){window.location.reload();}           
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `url` is a global var to the script